# Finding the centroid of a given curve

Tags: plotting, calculus-and-analysis, geometry

How to find  [Centroid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centroid) of the following curve?

```
curve = 
 Plot[Cos[x]/(x + Log[x]), {x, 1, 8}, Ticks -> None, PlotStyle -> {Blue, Thick}]
```

[image]

I tried:

```
Graphics[{curve, Red, Point[RegionCentroid[curve]]}]
```

but it doesn't work

Comment: Have you tried with `ParametricRegion[]`? `RegionCentroid[]` works on *regions* (as the function name implies) and not on `Graphics[]` objects.

Comment: Though it does work on graphics primitives (second example in the RegionCentroid documentation)

Answer (score 10):

For those, who wonder what we would do without `RegionCentroid`, there is the simple way of calculating the centre by normal integration. When we consider your function $f$ as parametric curve the situation is clear.

$$x(t)=t\\y(t)=\frac{\cos(t)}{t+\log(t)}$$

Furthermore, we need the [arc length](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arc_length) $L(f)$ of the curve which can be calculated with

$$ds=\sqrt{x'(t)^2+y'(t)^2}\;dt$$

Then your centre $(x_m, y_m)$ is given by

$$x_m\cdot L(f)=\int x\;ds\qquad y_m\cdot L(f)=\int y\;ds$$

For your particular case this means the x-coordinate of your centroid is given by

$$x_m = \left(\int_1^8 t\; ds\right)/(\int_1^8ds)$$

In *Mathematica* code

```
x[t_] := t;
y[t_] := Cos[t]/(t + Log[t]);

ds = Sqrt[x'[t]^2 + y'[t]^2];

NIntegrate[{x[t], y[t]} ds, {t, 1, 8}]/NIntegrate[ds, {t, 1, 8}]

(* {4.38467, -0.00815125} *)
```

Comment: It should be:`NIntegrate[{x*Sqrt[1 + dydx^2], y[x]*Sqrt[1 + dydx^2]}, {x, 1, 8}]/
 NIntegrate[Sqrt[1 + dydx^2], {x, 1, 8}]` ,`{4.38467, -0.00815125}`

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk I'm sorry. I didn't look it up. I'm fixing the post. Thanks for being attentive.

Answer (score 8):

To expand on J.M.'s comment, you will need to use the correct predicates to build the region (I used `ImplicitRegion` because I find it most flexible):

```
region = ImplicitRegion[y == (Cos[x]/(x + Log[x])) && x > 1 && x < 8, {x, y}];
```

Then you can use `RegionCentroid` on it:

```
centroid = RegionCentroid[DiscretizeRegion@region];
Show[RegionPlot[region], ListPlot[centroid], PlotLabel -> centroid]
```

[image: Centroid]

Answer (score 6):

Simplest is the numerical approach for `Graphics` objects, which is to use `DiscretizeGraphics`:

```
curve = Plot[Cos[x]/(x + Log[x]), {x, 1, 8}, Ticks -> None, PlotStyle -> {Blue, Thick}];
RegionCentroid[DiscretizeGraphics[curve]]

{4.3846982827317245, -0.008143914969936251}
```

Note, while you can get lucky with analytical results too sometimes:

```
RegionCentroid[ParametricRegion[{x, x^2}, {{x, 1, 8}}]]
```

$$\left\{\frac{257 \sqrt{257}-5 \sqrt{5}}{3 \left(-2 \sqrt{5}+16 \sqrt{257}-\sinh ^{-1}(2)+\sinh
   ^{-1}(16)\right)},\frac{-18 \sqrt{5}+8208 \sqrt{257}+\sinh ^{-1}(2)-\sinh ^{-1}(16)}{16 \left(-2
   \sqrt{5}+16 \sqrt{257}-\sinh ^{-1}(2)+\sinh ^{-1}(16)\right)}\right\}$$

Generally it is not the case:

[image]